# WCF RIA SERVICES and EF 4.1

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework-4.1, wcf-ria-services

Do I have to explicitly add the [Include] attribute for any entities that has ICollection property so that result LoadOperation callback will populate my entity with its collection?

Querying the data from the Service is fine, but when being passed to the LoadOperation it doesn't add the collection of a certain entity. Does it have something to do with serialization/deserialization from the service message?

If yes, what is the reason why? I have used EF with DbContext.Includes in WPF but I did not have any issues with my T4 template generated items when I wanted to query my entity's collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Include] attribute is required to advise the WCF marshaller to serialize related entities. Specifically, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.domainservices.server.includeattribute%28v=vs.91%29.aspx) advises

> this attribute specifies that the association should be part of any
>   code-generated client entities, and that any related entities should
>   be included when serializing results to the client.

You will still need to use the query.Include() on your DbContext to retrieve the related data from the database.

Comment: Spot on. It also lets RIA Services know to generated the specific classes client side.

Comment: So WCF is not yet smart enough to use EF's Mappings if I am using Code First that this certain table has this table. So MSDN is basically saying that as long as you are using a service that a client will consume. Your service class should always have the [Include] attribute?

Comment: It isn't necessarily because WCF isn't smart enough. A mature application could have a very complicated object tree and it doesn't not make sense to marshall every accessible object over the network. For instance, when you page through invoices, you already have the customer record on the client side and there is no point sending the customer record with every query.